# How to write to CakePHP 3.8 new Authentication plugin session

Tags: authentication, cakephp

I am using CakePHP 3.8 and CakePHP Authentication 2.x plugin to authentication. Everything is working right, put I want to change session authentication information while I am logged in. For example, I want to change admin rights on the session on the fly. In older CakePHP I could use next:

`$this->request->session()->write('Auth.User.adminLevel', 10);`

I can do it now still, but it destroys everything else from authentication array just leaving

`Array ( [User] => Array ( [adminLevel] => 10 ) )`

How can I write to AUTH -session?

Comment: The session object isn't part of the new plugin, it's still part of the Cake core, and this sort of update should certainly work. When you say it worked in "older CakePHP", what do you mean by older?

Comment: I mean 2.x and older 3.x versions.

Comment: Is your "write" code any different at all now than it was with other 3.x versions?